# Оканчивать 10, 11-й классы или класс?

Tags: грамотная-речь, множественное-число

10, 11 классы или класс? Как правильно?

Comment: Без контекста трудно ответить.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Учебные заведения ОКАНЧИВАЮТ, закончить - просторечие.

> Глагол *закончить* в значении "довести до конца, завершить"
> синонимичен *окончить*, правильно: *закончить* работу и *окончить*
> работу. ***В значении "пройти какой-либо курс обучения, завершить
> обучение где-либо" употребляется только глагол окончить: окончить
> школу, вуз, университет, курсы*** и т. п.

О наращениях в [Грамоте](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/letters/87-rubric-99) (gramota.ru/spravka) немножко избыточно для вопроса, однако полезно: хозяйке на заметку.

> Если подряд следуют два порядковых числительных, разделенных запятой
> или соединенных союзом, падежное окончание наращивают у каждого из
> них: 1-й, 2-й вагоны; 80-е и 90-е годы.
>
> Если подряд следуют более двух порядковых числительных, разделенных
> запятой, точкой с запятой или соединенных союзом, то падежное
> окончание наращивают только у последнего числительного: 1, 2 и 3-й
> вагоны, 70, 80, 90-е годы.
>
> **Если два порядковых числительных следуют через тире, то падежное окончание наращивают: а) только у второго числительного,** если
> падежное окончание у обоих числительных одинаковое: 50–60-е годы, в
> 80–90-х годах;
>
> б) у каждого числительного, если падежные окончания разные: в 11-м –
> 20-х рядах.

Если окончены оба класса (что следует из условия), то только множественное число:

*Окончить 10–11-й классы.*

Но у Вас форма "оканчивать"... Ускоренное обучение? Два класса за один учебный год?

И всё равно - множественное число:

*<Я собираюсь> оканчивать 10–11-й классы.*